# Amazon Web Services error

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have finished my assignment earlier today on cloud9 and when I returned to it today I found this error:

[image: The error I encountered]

I am relatively new to AWS and I am not sure what happened to my original code. Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

It looks like one of your source files has been overwritten with a binary.  (The ELF characters at the start are a big clue ...)

> Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Restore the missing file from backups or from your source code repository.  If you have neither of those, you will need to type in the missing file from memory.

There is no sensible way to recover lost C or C++ source code from a binary.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to find a way to revise the file history on Amazon Web Services and fix the file.